# Live stream Mongodb data to mongo cloud

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have set up a mongodb database on a ubuntu machine. Is there any possibility to stream my on-prem mongodb data to mongo cloud. As an when data is available on my on-prem mongodb the new data is to be streamed to mongo cloud.

If so how do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a change stream that would watch your on-prem deployment and perform corresponding modifications in your Atlas deployment.